# Calculate number of medals based on number of entries

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, mathematical-optimization

I have an app that awards the user based upon number of entries made.

- 10 entries = 1 bronze,
- 20 entries = 1 bronze, 1 silver,
- 30 entries = 1 bronze, 1 silver and 1 gold

It then repeats the cycle forever, always in multiples of 10.

- 40 entries = 2 bronze, 1 silver, 1 gold
- 50 entries = 2 silver, 2 silver, 1 gold
- 60 entries = 2 gold, 2 bronze and 2 gold

1-9 should show in progress for each level, and every tenth entry begins the next level. 1 is 10%, 9 is 90 % and rather than show 100%, just go straight to the next level.

I show a progress bar for the current level, a percentage of complete for current level, the icon of the level the user is going for. All of those currently show correctly.

The issue I'm facing is I also show a count for each level, which is only correct up to and including 44 entries. The 45th is where things start to go wrong.

Please check out the below or [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzok5sb0/1/) and feel free to edit.

```js
const DENOMINATOR = 10;

const clamp = (value: number, min: number, max: number): number => {
    return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}

const calculateAwardsByEntryCount = (count: number) => {
  const maxLevels = 3 * DENOMINATOR;
  const modulus = count % maxLevels;
  const currentLevel = Math.max(0, Math.floor(modulus / DENOMINATOR) - 1);
  const nextLevel = Math.min(3, currentLevel + 1);
  const prestige = Math.ceil((count + 1) / maxLevels);
  const progress = ((modulus - DENOMINATOR * nextLevel) / DENOMINATOR) * 100;

  let bronze = 0;
  let silver = 0;
  let gold = 0;

  if (count >= DENOMINATOR) {
    bronze = count <= maxLevels ? 1 : Math.floor(modulus / (DENOMINATOR - 1)) * prestige;
  }

  if (count >= DENOMINATOR * 2 && bronze > 0) {
    silver = count <= maxLevels ? 1 : clamp(Math.ceil(modulus / (DENOMINATOR * 2 - 1)) * prestige, 0, bronze + 1);
  }

  if (count >= DENOMINATOR * 3 && silver > 0) {
    gold = count <= maxLevels ? 1 : clamp(Math.ceil((modulus / (DENOMINATOR * 3 - 1)) * prestige), 0, silver + 1);
  }

  return {
    achieved: {bronze, silver, gold},
    currentLevel,
    nextLevel,
    progress,
  }
}

console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(45));
```

Comment: I see no reason to use min/max - all of this can be easily achieved with modulo maths

Comment: @meowgoesthedog please provide an amended jsfiddle to demonstrate what you mean. I'm wondering if I've explained it correctly.

Comment: I've just updated to clarify how it should work

Comment: I don't quite understand your definition of a "level". On the one hand you clamp `nextLevel` to the number of medals, implying that a "level" is simply the rank of its corresponding medal; on the other `maxLevels` is defined to be the total number of *entries* required for a full set of medals. I can only assume that the former is (more) correct. Also, did you mean to write `50 entries = 2 bronze, 2 silver, 1 gold` and `60 entries = 2 bronze, 2 silver and 2 gold`?

Comment: Yes, I did mean to write `50 entries = 2 bronze, 2 silver, 1 gold` and `60 entries = 2 bronze, 2 silver and 2 gold`. I clamped silver and gold to ensure that gold never goes higher than silver and silver never goes higher than bronze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly the most efficient solution, but at least it 100% accurate for any number of entries.

```js
const DENOMINATOR = 10;

const calculateAwardsByEntryCount = (count: number) => {
  let remainingProgress = count;
  let currentLevel = null;
  let bronze = 0;
  let silver = 0;
  let gold = 0;

  for (remainingProgress; remainingProgress >= DENOMINATOR; remainingProgress -= DENOMINATOR) {
    switch (currentLevel) {
      case 1:
        currentLevel = 2;
        gold += 1;
        break;
      case 0:
        currentLevel = 1;
        silver += 1;
        break;
      default:
        currentLevel = 0;
        bronze += 1;
        break;
    }
  }


  if (currentLevel === null) {
    currentLevel = -1
  }
  
  const progress = (remainingProgress / DENOMINATOR) * 100;
  const nextLevel = currentLevel === 2 ? 0 : currentLevel + 1;

  return {
    achieved: {
      bronze,
      silver,
      gold
    },
    nextLevel,
    progress,
  };
}

console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(9));
console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(10));
console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(20));
console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(30));
console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(35));
console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(45));
console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(55));
console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(65));
console.log(calculateAwardsByEntryCount(75));
```

Comment: `calculateAwardsByEntryCount(10)` returns `bronze:0, silver:1, gold:0`. Is this result correct?

Comment: Have corrected the snippet above. Now it's definitely correct